# Investing Calculator

Tags: java

Hey I've built this code so far to do compound interest over the course of x years but I Do Not know How to include a "x amount of dollars per year added to the funds." So If I make my variable $70,000 it will compound interest for x amount of years, the difficulty is in adding "y amount of dollars each year, along with the initial amount invested." Code posted Below

```
 import java.util.*;
//Feel Free To Steal My Code  Sincerely Minotaur,

public class Investing {

public static void main (String[] args){

        Scanner input1 = new Scanner(System.in);

        double amount;

        double principal;

        double rate;

        System.out.println("Please Enter The Principal");
        principal = input1.nextDouble();

        System.out.println("Please Enter The Rate Of Interest In Decimal Form");
        rate = input1.nextDouble();

        System.out.println("Please Enter The Number Of Investment Years");
        Scanner input2 = new Scanner (System.in);
        int g = input2.nextInt();

        for(int year = 1; year <= g; year++){
            amount = principal * Math.pow(1 + rate, year);
            System.out.println(year + "  " + amount);

        }           
    }       
}
```

Comment: So what's the problem? I don't understand what you're saying. By a quick glance that looks just fine.

Comment: logic error @minotaur

Comment: I felt I didn't explain it clear enough, So if I have a base amount invested to be compounded annually at a fixed rate my program does that, what I want to add is a set amount of money to the investment each year to be compounded with the Base amount, So if I put 10000 in at first and 1000 every year after that to be compounded with the 10000

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In stead of  recomputing the value from the principal, compute it from the previous year:

```
amount = principal;
for(int year = 1; year <= g; year++){
    amount *= 1 + rate;
    System.out.println(year + "  " + amount);
}
```

Then in order to add a specific amount each year simply add to the amount

```
amount = principal;
for(int year = 1; year <= g; year++){
    amount *= 1 + rate;
    amount+=<amount to add>;
    System.out.println(year + "  " + amount);
}
```

Comment: Perfect Exactly what I was looking for, I would like to ask how the "amount+ = <number>; line works though for future reference

Comment: @Minotaur it is one of the compound assignment operators. All it is is a shorthand for `amount= amount+<amount to add>;`  The same can be done, say , if you want to divide a number by 3: `number/=3` is the same as `number = number/3` see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html for the full list.

Answer (score 0):

```
  amount = principal * Math.pow((1 + rate/100),time);
```

instead of

```
amount = principal * Math.pow(1 + rate, year);
```

the code i use to  take out compound interest :-(optimized)

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class CompoundInterest {

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

      double principal = 0;
      double rate = 0;
      double time = 0;

      double compoundInterest = 0;

      System.out.print("Enter the Principal amount : ");
      principal = input.nextDouble();

      System.out.print("Enter the Rate : ");
      rate = input.nextDouble();

      System.out.print("Enter the Time : ");
      time = input.nextDouble();

      compoundInterest = principal * Math.pow((1 + rate/100),time);

      System.out.println("");
      System.out.println("The Compound Interest is : "
     + compoundInterest);

   }

}
```

Comment: This is unlikely to be what he's asking for. Note that the program already receives inputs in decimal form.